# Generate vector field pointing to minimum intensity (black)

Tags: plotting, vector

I have a black and white image and want to plot a vector field that points to the highest and nearest minimum intensity value (something like the arrows shown in the image). Similar to Gradient filter but that gives me the change in intensity.

[image]

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer without precise specification of the goal, because "highest" and "nearest" are in direct competition.

Comment: Like a distance transform, if it is too far it's intensity decreases at that point. So for example 20 pixels from 10 pixel density ~= 10 pixels from 5 pixel density.